# Need transactions to timeout when there is a table lock

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a situation where I'm trying to lock a table, and then view transactions trying to hit same table. I want them to timeout after a certain period of time.

```
lock tables <table_in_question> WRITE;
```

Then I will view open transactions with following query:

```
show open tables where table like '<table_in_question>' and database like '<database>' and in_use > 0;
```

I'm trying to wait for these transactions to timeout but they aren't for some reason.

I thought that innodb_lock_wait_timeout set to 50 seconds might cause these transactions to time out, but then I noticed this setting only applies to the row level.

What setting do I need to adjust or what variable do I need to change so these transactions attempting to write to this table timeout?

Comment: Waiting for a table lock... just waits.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have yet to discover a valid use for `LOCK TABLE` in InnoDB.  Please explain your use case; maybe you have discovered one?

Comment: Trying to test what happens when system breaks to a transaction (ie., altering a table with a lock statement to drop a column) while other transactions are trying to insert data